# How to get command output of “nvidia-settings” via command line?

Tags: grep, sed, nvidia-settings

the case at hand:

nvidia-settings -q all | grep 'Attribute.*GPUCoreTemp'

gives:

```
Attribute 'GPUCoreTemp' (system5:0.0) 58.                              
Attribute 'GPUCoreTemp' (system5:0[gpu:0]): 58.
```

then I make it:

```
nvidia-settings -q all | grep 'Attribute.*GPUCoreTemp' |  sed -e 's/.* //'
```

gives me:

```
58.

58.
```

But I only want the first one... How to achieve this?

Answer (score 2):

Pass grep the `-m 1` switch, to limit to only one matching output. See `man grep`.

Comment: Life can be soooo simple :) thx!  I always get lost in man pages somehow, esp. the long ones.

Comment: No problem, and glad to help! :-) Please accept my answer if this worked for you.

Answer (score 1):

Use -t query option

```
$ nvidia-settings -t -q [gpu:0]/GPUCoreTemp
56
```